# Interference with 2 Jsoup connections to the same site in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup

I have the next code:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0){
        try {
            Connection conn = Jsoup.connect("http://m.mismarcadores.com/partido/"+id+"/");

            Document docDatosPartido = conn.get();
            extraerDatosPartido(docDatosPartido);

            Document docAlineaciones = conn.data("t","alineaciones").get();
            extraerAlineaciones(docAlineaciones);

            Document docVideos = Jsoup.connect("http://d.mismarcadores.com/x/feed/d_hi_"+id+"_es_1").header("X-Fsign","SW9D1eZo").get();
            extraerVideos(docVideos);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); System.out.println("ha fallado al coger los links");
        }
        return null;
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {          
        activity.updateView();
        activity.anyadirDatosTabAcciones();
        activity.anyadirDatosTabAlineaciones();
        activity.anyadirDatosTabVideos();
    }
}
```

The problem is that sometimes, "docAlineaciones" is equals to "docDatosPartidos", it seems like the first conn.get() interferes in the second get(), but only sometimes. If I change the connections orders de problem is upside down.

With the third connection I don't have any problem, I think it is because the website url is different.

Comment: Someone can help me, Its very frustated that a simple assignment doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

```
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.yourURLhere.com/").get();
```

Use this ONCE. Then get the information out of the document using document.select(), etc.